# Sending URLs browser to server netcat from my Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, server, netcat

i try to create a plugin for send the  url (when i switch tab or open ) to my netcat server  it listen 127.0.0.1:4444 (netcat -l 4444), i have creted  3  file
manifest.json

```
"name": "Connector 4 Terminal", 
"version": "1.0", 
"description": "Connector 4 Terminal",
"browser_action": {
"default_popup": "popup.html",
"default_icon":"icon.png"
 },

"manifest_version":2,
"permissions": [
"tabs",
"<all_urls>"
]
}  

background.js
 
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
if (changeInfo != undefined) {
var http = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  http.open("POST",
  "127.0.0.1:4444", 
   true);
  sendme = changeInfo.url
   http.send(sendme);
}
alert(sendme);
}); 

popup.html

<html>
    <head>
       <title>Connector 4 Terminal</title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Connector 4 Terminal</h1>
        <p><a target="_blank"href="127.0.0.1:4444">Connector 4 Terminal</a></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

the  plugin loading  without error but not send at my  netcat the url anyone can help me ?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

xhttp request can not be made through background.js
you can use fetch api for the same purpose

```
let response = await fetch('127.0.0.1:4444', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: changeInfo.url
    });
```

make sure to use it in async funcation.

Comment: sorry i dont have much experience  with javascript  and  plugin for chrome  i modify background.js  with your code i think is  correct but  not return nothing    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
if (changeInfo != undefined) {
let response = await fetch('127.0.0.1:4444', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: changeInfo.url
    });
}
alert(sendme);
});

Comment: actually alert function doesn't work in background.js, so you can test it with console.log() and you async be function keyword

Comment: but  how  can do it ? you have  a  compleate  example ?? , i look in Console  but not appear nothing when i surf or change  url address thanks